# Paypal Error: Dispatch Error, please check logfile for more information

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm creating a Recurring Payment Profile on Paypal, first step is I logged in on the developer.paypal.com website and entered on sandbox website then logged a sandbox account credentails.

Then upon redirecting for Paypal Authorization (see link below)
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-5N576060NN902951N

I get this error:
*Paypal Error: Dispatch Error, please check logfile for more information*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I shouldn't log on my developer paypal account and just use the sandbox account, which is different from before.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are not using the latest version of the api your redirect url should be

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=EC-5N576060NN902951N